# How to call a checkbox within class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I tried to put some conditions as in the following procedure

```
public float GetSimilarity(int doc_i, int doc_j)
    {
        float[] vector1 = GetTermVector(doc_i);
        float[] vector2 = GetTermVector(doc_j);

      if (checkbox1.checked == true )

         return Similarties.ComputeDiceSimilarity(vector1, vector2);

      else if (checkbox2.checked == true )

        return Similarties.ComputeCosineSimilarity(vector1, vector2);

      else 

         return Similarties.ComputeJaccardSimilarity(vector1, vector2);
    }
```

, but the problem is the checkboxes  are not recognized within the class. how to overcome this issue please? . Sorry for the poor programming and thanks in advance.

Comment: is this webforms? asp, wpf?

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows Form application in C#

Comment: Where are the checkboxes declared?

Comment: and thats weird if that checkbox is declared inside the class(form)`:D`

Comment: @  spajce , what do you mean please ?

Comment: if you actually declared or dragged a checkbox to your `form` the checkbox should be recognizable

Comment: but you can follow of Mr. Tim Schmelter advice.. `var sim = GetSimilarity(1, 2, checkbox1.checked, checkbox2.checked)`

Comment: The class I'm using is separate.

Comment: just follow the first answer, just call the method something like → `var sim = GetSimilarity(1, 2, checkbox1.checked, checkbox2.checked)`

Comment: the checkbox is not recognized from the class. it is only recognized from the public partial class Form1 : Form !!! how to call it ?

Comment: @Falah, does the class containing function GetSimilarity sits outside of your from ? If this is the case, **please try moving the function inside the from where you have your check boxes declared.** As suggested by others a better approach would be to calculate e the what check box is checked outside method GetSimilarity and pass it in as a parameter. This way, GetSimilarity becomes neutral of the from controllers and you will be able to reuse the logic.

Comment: @  Chintana, I can't move function inside the form because it needs a lot of work. But the second choice as the other suggested, really i don't know how to do it. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need direct access to controls in a method in a different class that should calculate something? Hard-linking UI with your business logic will avoid reusable code.

You could pass the variables as arguments:

```
public float GetSimilarity(int doc_i, int doc_j, 
    bool compDiceSimilarity, bool compCosineSimilarity)
{
    float[] vector1 = GetTermVector(doc_i);
    float[] vector2 = GetTermVector(doc_j);

    if (compDiceSimilarity)
        return Similarties.ComputeDiceSimilarity(vector1, vector2);
    else if (compCosineSimilarity)
        return Similarties.ComputeCosineSimilarity(vector1, vector2);
    else
        return Similarties.ComputeJaccardSimilarity(vector1, vector2);
}
```

By the way, you should really use more meaningful names for your controls and variables.

Comment: @ Tim, what about the checkbox ?

Comment: @Falah: So where is this method and it's class, in the same class as the form or maybe in a nested class. Perhaps in a different class, in a different namespace or even in a different assembly? You haven't told us much, so i've answered generally since using a control as input wouldn't be the correct way anyway.

Comment: @ Tim, the method in a separate class. Not in the from

Comment: @Falah: If you want to access a field/property/control(variable in general) from another class that variable must either be `public static`, then you can access it via `className.PropertyName` or you need an instance of the other class in this class. It could be passed as parameter or it could be a field in your class. However, the only correct way in this case is passing the required variables  as arguments to this method.

Comment: @ Tim, but i want to use the checkbox. How to link the bools with checkbox. The thing I want is to put 2 checkboxes, when the user check any of them, the desired similarity method have to run.

Comment: @Falah: Then handle their [`CheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) events and call this method. You can pass the `checkBox.Checked` property as method argument.